# Delegate that does not keep the target alive

Tags: c#, garbage-collection, delegates

Is there a way to prevent a delegate from keeping the target alive?

If I have `Action a = someObj.DoSomething`, `someObj` will be kept alive by the the delegate.

If I have `WeakReference<Action> a = new WeakReference<Action>((Action)someObj.DoSomething)`, `someObj` will still be kept alive by the delegate, but the delegate itself will be collected by the GC, and then the target can be collected.

Comment: So you basically want an entirely nondeterministic delegate, which may or may not invoke `DoSomething`?

Answer (score 1):

You simply want to have a delegate that *uses* a weak reference, rather than a weak reference to a delegate.

```
WeakReference<YourObjectType> someObjReference = new WeakReference<YourObjectType>(someObj);
Action a = () =>
{
    if (someObjReference.TryGetTarget(out YourObjectType someObjValue))
        someObjValue.DoSomething();
};
```

Comment: But in this scenario I must know that the object has the method "DoSomething". I'd like a general solution, so I can just assign a method to a variable: `weakDel = someObj.DoSomething`, or at least pass it to a method: `CreateWeakDel(someObj.DoSomething)`, or something like that.

Comment: @Markonius And yet that's not what your question is asking.  If you want to write a method with that signature exactly it's going to be *quite* hard.  If you want to write a method accepting a reference to an object, and a delegate taking that object's type as a parameter, then you can just use this code but call the delegate instead of the method.

Answer (score -1):

I think what you have done is right and something else is holding you object.

I been testing with

```
    class Program
    {
        public class YourObjectType {
            public void DoSomething() { }
        }
        public class WeakReferences {
            public WeakReference<Action> a;
            public WeakReference<YourObjectType> o;
        }

        static WeakReferences createReferences() {
            var someObj = new YourObjectType();

            return new WeakReferences() { a = new WeakReference<Action>((Action)someObj.DoSomething), o = new WeakReference<YourObjectType>(someObj) };
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            WeakReferences wr = createReferences();
            YourObjectType o = null;
            wr.o.TryGetTarget(out o); //comment this line to collect it instead
            GC.Collect();
            Action a = null;

            Console.WriteLine(wr.a.TryGetTarget(out a));
            Console.WriteLine(wr.o.TryGetTarget(out o));
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

and indeed if you avoid the first TryGetTarget it will be gone.

Comment: The problem with this solution is not that it holds onto the object when it shouldn't, the problem is that *nothing* is holding onto the delegate, so it gets immediately garbage collected, even if the object reference used by the delegate is still around.  What's needed is a strong reference to a delegate where that delegate uses a weak reference to the object `DoSomething` is invokved on.